# achartengine line chart graphical bug (maybe)

Tags: android, achartengine, linechart

I have a simple line chart in full view. When first generate the chart under one black line. (see in pictures)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0YK4.jpg

its just in first generate, i make repaint every 30 second with new dataset and after the chart ok, no black line.

Here my Chart Settings:

```
rendere.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    rendere.setFillBelowLine(true);
    rendere.setFillBelowLineColor(context.getResources().getColor(
            R.color.chartstart));

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendere);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("");
    mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    mRenderer.setFitLegend(false);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(min);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(max);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }); // Top
    mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    mRenderer.setXLabels(6);
    mRenderer.setYLabels(6);
```

Why is there a black bar at the first appearance?
thx

Comment: I change the marginsColor and the problem there. Just i don't know why:(

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a bug with the transparency.  I think Color.TRANSPARENT is black with an alpha 0.  For some reason the black (all 0s) will still show as black

Try the following code

```
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
```